# jQuery function not registering in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, enqueue

I am trying to add a script on my Wordpress site.
Using jQuery I want add an "onChange" event to a numeric input (which belongs to the Calculated Fields Form plugin).

When I type something in the input field, nothing happens. It should have printed `onChange` in console.

So the problem is that the jQuery functions are not registering.

HTML:

```
<input id="fieldname2_1" name="fieldname2_1" min="1" type="number">
```

functions.php file:

```
function numeric_input_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'numeric-input', // naming my script so that i can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/numeric-input.js', // this is the location of the script file
        array('jquery'), // this array lists the scripts upon which my script depends
        null, // version number
        true // states that the script needs to be loaded in the footer
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'numeric_input_script' );
```

JS file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log('Loading'); //shows up

    $('#fieldname2_1').on('change', function() {
        console.log("onChange"); //code inside this function does not work
    })

    console.log('Loaded');  //shows up
});
```

Things that I have tried, but with no success:

- buttons and other events;
- enqueuing the script after the header (last param of `wp_enqueue_script` set to false);
- using `var j = jQuery.noConflict();` and using `j` instead of `$`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I assume the issue is related to the plugin. Can you tell more about this plugin?

Comment: I did some tests and you are right. The plugin is called Calculated Fields Form. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is registered but the actual issue is caused by the Calculated Fields Form plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
jQuery('#fieldname2_1').on('change', function() {
   console.log("onChange"); //code inside this function does not work
})
```

The `$` alias is not binded to avoid conflict

Comment: It is not a problem, since I have gave `$` as a parameter to the document ready function. I have found out that the issue is caused by the plugin I was mentioning.